# "(" was not closed Pylance any help pls?

Tags: xpath

that's the line of the code where am getting the error

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div").click()

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```py
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginForm']/div/div[3]/button/div").click()
```